# Script autorun in after effects

Tags: adobe, extendscript, after-effects

I'm about to create an After Effects script. In future, I would like to make it autorun at a certain point of a day (every hour perhaps). How can I autorun a script or series of scritps ? Is there something like CRON for PHP ?

Thank you!

Comment: You can send scripts from the command line to AE. So you could use crontab with a shell script (in Mac) have a look into the AE scripting guide http://blogs.adobe.com/aftereffects/files/2012/06/After-Effects-CS6-Scripting-Guide.pdf?file=2012/06/After-Effects-CS6-Scripting-Guide.pdf